# How to get access to functions from within more than one class

Tags: java, selenium

I have one main class that executes functions written in another class, let's call it "code" class. Now I have created one more "code" class and I want to call the functions there as well. I don't want to create more than one object in my main class, as I have constructors in both code classes and creating multiple objects will screw with my tests. I can't extend more than one class as I know. Is there any other solution for me to call the functions in the second code class without creating an object of that class?

```
ReqOrderImpMain d = new ReqOrderImpMain(); 
//Request Order Import - First page function calling 
d.page(); 
d.checkLoginAndProceed(); 
/*d.output(); 
  d.correctORNumber(); 
  d.createNewOrder(); 
  d.checkOrder(); 
  d.checkSend(); 
  d.quantityCheck(); 
  d.restMatWithQuantity(); 
  d.submit(); 
  d.quit();*/ 
  //Request Order Import - Rest of the pages function calling ??.output(); ??.select();
}
```

Functions with d. are called from the first code class. I want to be able to call the ??.function() ones.

Comment: First of all your design sounds really confusing, why are there 2 "code" classes and why are they both named "code"? Do you not have access to source code of the FIRST code class? Can you not just WRAP the FIRST code class in the SECOND code class and return an instance of FIRST from SECOND whenever you need to call methods on the FIRST code class? You should really add some source code to your question (even simple example), it sounds like you have a design problem and you're not approaching it correctly.

Comment: So it's like this: I have one main class, right? There i only call functions. The code before is from my main class, with my main method. Then i have another class for handling Request Order Import, where i have implemented methods like d.page(), d.checkLoginAndProceed etc. And now i have to test other pages that are part of Request Order Import, but they are different. That is why i would like to have another class for them, not to include all code inside a single class...seems sloppy like that. Do you have any ideas? Or the only way is for me to write all implementation into a single class?

Comment: Added your code to the question, but you may want to go over it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call functions (methods) in a class without creating an instance of that class, you need to create static methods.

```
public class ClassWithStaticMethod { 

  public static void staticMethod() {
      ...
  }

}
```

You can call the method like this (no instance required):

```
ClassWithStaticMethod.staticMethod();
```

It sounds like you may have backed yourself into a corner with your tests though, and may want to consider redesigning your code / tests. I don't think test code should ever decide how your actual code looks or works.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I can't make static methods because then i'm getting errors all over the place with "cannot use non-static reference to a static...". So at the moment, i have one main class where i just call functions and two other where i write the functions, and i don't want to write all functions inside the same class. What do you think, how should i design my tests? What is the correct way?

Comment: You cannot call non-static methods from static methods, because in the static case there is no `this`. I think your design would be alot easier without the following requirement: "I don't want to create more than one object in my main class". Why is that?

Comment: Well, i really want to create more objects :D The problem is that both classes have a constructor for handling errors. When i instantiate the other class, instead of running the methods in both classes Firefox opens 2 blank pages and do nothing. However, if i comment the creation of the second object my tests run smooth. If you have an idea about creating another object without them interfering with each other, please shoot! That would be the best solution to this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Since you want only one object, but use the results of the functions of your second class, you have to either assign them to your first object (1) (via some attributes) or just let them run on some input (2)(in case they are void).

1) firstCodeClassObject.someAttribute = SecondCodeclass.doSomeMethod(inputType input);

2) SecondCodeclass.doSomeMethod(inputType input);

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the answer. I just have to initialize driver in main class, then create a constructor and pass the driver reference to the other two classes.